# IndexDefect Issue In Nim

Tags: arrays, nim-lang

I am trying to learn Nim, so picked up [this](https://narimiran.github.io/nim-basics/#_exercises_3) so, the first problem says:

```
Create an empty array which can contain ten integers.

    Fill that array with numbers 10, 20, …​, 100. (Hint: use loops)

    Print only the elements of that array that are on odd indices (values 20, 40, …​).

    Multiply elements on even indices by 5. Print the modified array.
```

I tried,

```
var a: array[10, int]
for i in countup(0,100,10):
    a[i] = i
echo a
```

It shows error with IndexEffect, I know am try to index more than 10 which is wrong but I cannot find any new other ways to do this, any help with the code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way might be something like this:

```
var a: array[10, int]
for i in 1..10:
  a[i - 1] = i * 10
echo a
```